# Watir, locate element by custom attribute

Tags: ruby, selenium, testing, automation, watir

I am using Watir 6.16 and I have come across this line of code

```
<div data-guid="SearchTitle" class="acme"></div>
```

Not sure how to locate such an element in Watir, I have tried this -

```
element(:search_title, custom_attribute: "SearchTitle")
```

But this returns nothing, so am I forced to use xpath or is there another way?

Kev

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change that `-` into `_`, it would work. Look at the code below

```
browser.div(data_guid: 'SearchTitle')
```

Comment: I didn't know about the underscore, I always used `browser.div('data-guid': 'SearchTitle')` in case of dashes in the attribute.

Comment: @Gijs Paulides Okay. Great! The way you used I was not knowing it. Good to know.